# How to know the locale that has been used to initialize a Postgres server?

Tags: postgresql, locales

I need it in order to create a new database with `initdb` with the same locale, otherwise `pg_upgrade` will fail.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use `psql -l`, but it outputs many lines if there a lot of databases.

Answer (score 0):

When upgrading to postgresql 16 or later, this is no longer relevant. The locale and encoding match requirement has been removed as redundant, pg_upgrade now copies the encoding settings itself: https://github.com/postgres/postgres/commit/9637badd9f9209166140eb567602e91699dd2ffb

When upgrading to postgresql 15 or older, the most important are the locale settings for the database named `template0`.

```
psql -c '\l template0'
```

initdb should be called with same `--encoding=... --locale=... --lc-collate=...`